# React - Redux: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, array, react

Estou tentando renderizar alguns produtos vindos da minha api, porém recebo este erro: *TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined*

Segue o código da action:

```
export const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
    });
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get('/api/products');
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, payload: error.message });
    }
  };
```

Código do reducer:

```
export const productListReducer = (state = { loading: true, products: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true };
    case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
      return {
        loading: false,
        products: action.payload.products,
      };
    case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

E por fim, código da página que será renderizada:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { listProducts } from '../../../actions/productActions';
import './style.css';

export default function PageProducts() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
    const { products } = productList;

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(listProducts());
    }, [dispatch]);

    return (
        <>
            <section className="card-last-prod">
                <h2>Últimos produtos</h2>
                <div className="card-last-pro-grid">
                    {products.map((product) => (
                        <div key={product._id} className="card-last-prod-item">
                            <Link to="/">
                                <div className="card-last-prod-item-img">
                                    <img src={product.img} alt="" />
                                </div>
                                <div className="btn">
                                    <button> Detalhes</button>
                                </div>
                                <p>{product.name}</p>
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </section>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O reducer por padrão sempre retorna um objeto **NOVO** para colocar no estado, sendo assim na sua ação `PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST` você precisa retornar a lista `products` :

```
 case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
  return { products: [], loading: true };
```

ou o estado anterior, a forma mais comum de se fazer que é sempre copiar o que tinha no estado, mudando apenas a propriedade desejada:

```
 case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
  return { ...state, loading: true };
```

Comment: Fiz o que disse, continuo com o mesmo erro.
Já chequei o path no axios, já fiz requisições de autenticação também e está tudo ok..inclusive a requisição de produtos funciona normalmente no insomnia, não sei o que pode ser isso.

Comment: Como está o retorno da api?

Answer (score -2):

Também estou com o mesmo problema que a pessoa, só coloquei a imagem que provavelmente é o mesmo problema, só queria ajuda também lol

[image: meu código]
O problema é que por algum motivo ele fica dando erro na leitura do código

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).